# Standard algorithms any_of(), all_of() and none_of() applied on empty ranges

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a question related to stl algorithms.

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/ I see that `any_of()`, `all_of()` and `none_of()` have different return values when applied on empty range, but it seems that it is only consequence of their implementations.

What do you consider to be correct return values of these algorithms? Does set theory answer these questions?

Comment: As a side note: I'd recommend [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) preferably.

Comment: The choices (`all_of`: true, `any_of`: false, `none_of`: true) are presumably based on the properties of the universal and existential operators of predicate logic.

Comment: Related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic

Answer (score 8):

You simply interpret their name. Use common sense. That is:

`any_of` does any element in range fulfill the condition? For this, you need at least one matching element.

`all_of` does all elements in range fulfill the condition? If no elements are there, then all of them meet the criteria.

etc.

The pattern is quite simple:

- If you check for *existence* (∃ x: P(x)) you need at least one element.
  [Existential_quantification_The_empty_set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_quantification#The_empty_set)
- If you check for universality (∀ x: P(x)) then an empty set is fine.
  [Universal_quantification_The_empty_set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification#The_empty_set)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64907/discussion-on-answer-by-karoly-horvath-standard-algorithms-any-of-all-of-an).

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: you should have kept the useful stuff here... it wasn't purely chat-noise!

Comment: it appears to be a live conversation; that's not what the comments are for. Edit the useful information into your answer or the question as appropriate.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I also would have preferred some posts to remain, but anyway. It's just one guy not getting it and the answer is good enough for the rest of the world.

Comment: @stefan the good news is that you can go visit the comments that were migrated to the chat site and edit the gems into the answer if you really want them to remain.  If, however, you want ephemeral comments to stick around without any work on your part, you are on the wrong site.

Comment: I find it highly illogical that in most cases `all_of` is a stricter check than `any_of`, but in this corner case `any_of` can be false while `all_of` is true. This seems contradictory.

Answer (score 1):

This is not about implementation, the standard is pretty clear on what they should return

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf

you can check on page 846 for any_of for example

Returns: false if [first,last) is empty or if there is no iterator i in the range [first,last) such
that pred(*i) is true, and true otherwise.